# Intellisense not helping

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am writing some code for a Windows application and things are going alright except for the IntelliSense doesn't give me options in some click event scope. Surprisingly, when I code it without its help, it doesn't give me any red squiggly on that line of code, so I am assuming the scope thing is OK.

I have two forms, `FormA` and `FormB`, a button click event on `FormA` should trigger `FormB` with its textboxes filled with the information it received after running the logic attached. How I am doing is

```
formSrchResult.txtSearchFirstName.Text = searchedInfo.FirstName;
formSrchResult.txtSearchLastName.Text = searchedInfo.LastName;
formSrchResult.txtSearchUsername.Text = searchedInfo.UserName;
formSrchResult.txtSearchEmail.Text = searchedInfo.Email;
```

`formSearchResult` is an object of a `FormSearch(FormB)` and `searchedInfo` is an object of a class which have the properties storing data, which I want the textboxes in `FormSearch` to display. Both the `FormSearch` and `searchedInfo` are declared public, yet when I start typing

> "formSrchResult." + "ctrl + space"

IntelliSense gives me no list with the names of textboxes and properties. So, I was wondering if anyone would have any idea on what might be causing this, I would love to know. Btw, its Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks.

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

That is the class which would store the searched info and below is the code for search method...

```
public UserInfo Search(string email)
{
    UserInfo searchUserInfo = new UserInfo();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spListEverything", conn);
        cmd.CommandText = "spListEverything";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);

        SqlDataReader rdrSearch = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdrSearch.Read())
        {
            //why do we need to convert the first name, last name etc to ToString
            //when they are defined, in the database, as a string itself?
            searchUserInfo.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(rdrSearch["UserID"]);
            searchUserInfo.FirstName = rdrSearch["FirstName"].ToString();
            searchUserInfo.LastName = rdrSearch["LastName"].ToString();
            searchUserInfo.UserName = rdrSearch["UserName"].ToString();
            searchUserInfo.Email = rdrSearch["Email"].ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            // "Sorry, no match found";
        }

        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
       conn.Close();
    }
    return searchUserInfo;
}
```

Below is my coding for the btnClick event where the Intellisense did not help

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = txtSearchEmail.Text.ToString();

    Manage myManage = new Manage(); //to call the search function
    FormSearchResult formSrchResult = new FormSearchResult();//to put the vlaues in the textboxes in that form

    UserInfo searchedInfo = myManage.Search(email);

    //the search function is not working properly. No value is returned to be stored
    //in the userInfo object

    //Here for some reason my intellisense is not providing options.

    formSrchResult.txtSearchFirstName.Text = searchedInfo.FirstName;
    formSrchResult.txtSearchLastName.Text = searchedInfo.LastName;
    formSrchResult.txtSearchUsername.Text = searchedInfo.UserName;
    formSrchResult.txtSearchEmail.Text = searchedInfo.Email;

    txtSearchFirstName.Enabled = false;
    formSrchResult.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Don't assume scope is right by only relying to the intellisense. Try to compile the project and check for the possible errors.

Comment: What is the access level of the property or field that you are trying to access..? perhaps if you would show the actual class definition it would help in resolving this issue you are facing\

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms controls are not static properties of forms, thus you need to create an object of type formSrchResult to be able to access any of its controls from another class. Classes need to have static methods or properties to be called without a direct reference to an object of that type.

Something like this:

```
public partial class FormB : Form
{
    private formSrchResult formSR; // this is a private field that is accessible to any method in your FormB class - you must initialize it first before trying to do anything on the object or you will receive a null reference

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchResult searchedInfo = DoSearch();
        formSR = new formSrchResult();
        formSR.txtSearchFirstName.Text = searchedInfo.FirstName;
        formSR.txtSearchLastName.Text = searchedInfo.LastName;
        formSR.txtSearchUsername.Text = searchedInfo.UserName;
        formSR.txtSearchEmail.Text = searchedInfo.Email;
        formSR.Show();
    }

    private SearchResult DoSearch()
    { 
        // your code
    }
}
```

You may also want to make the formSrchResult object globally accessible by your FormB class so you would declare that as a private field. This way you can access your object from any method in your class. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I apologize but I am not able to see how the code snippet you provided is different from what I have. I have created an object of FormSearch as frmSearchResult and UserInfo as searched info. As mentioned by @DJ KRAZE below are my code snippets for the classes..

public class UserInfo
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I have added my code snippets to my main post, if that would be any helpful. Also Cameron, when you suggested me to make my formSrchResult object globally accessible what did you meant by that. My FormSearchResult has a public scope by default, isn't that supposed to make it globally accessible. I thank-you all for your time.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include what I was talking about by making a private field for your search result form. Also, does your code build as it is now without errors?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into that and make a revision. I got that thing working. What I did was went to the textbox and changed it's modifiers properties to "internal" from "private." I read somewhere in the forum that it is not a good practice and told its better if we create a public properties for that. I tried to do that but I haven't worked that way yet... I thank you all very much.